# CONNECTIVITY_ACTION intent received twice when Wifi connected

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-broadcastreceiver

In my app I have a `BroadcastReceiver` that is launched as a component through a `<receiver>` tag, filtering `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE` intents.

My goal is simply to know when a Wifi connection was established, so what I am doing in `onReceive()` is this:

```
NetworkInfo networkInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
if(networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
    // Wifi is connected
}
```

It works fine, but I always seem to get two identical intents within about one second when a Wifi connection is established. I tried to look at any info I could get from the intent, the `ConnectivityManager` and `WifiManager`, but I can't find anything that distinguishes the two intents.

Looking at the log, there is at least one other `BroadcastReceiver` that also receives the two identical intents.

It is running on a HTC Desire with Android 2.2

Any idea why I seem to get a "duplicated" intent when Wifi connects or what the difference between the two might be?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLrnPJCHvNZuBqr_0AS9BPXgU6gvNeai5S
A good understanding of recent methods of implementing broadcast receivers

Answer (score 63, accepted):

**NOTE:** For a recent, up-to-date answer, see [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54538895/709426) below!

After a lot of googling and debugging, I believe this is the correct way to determine if Wifi has connected or disconnected.

The `onReceive()` method in the BroadcastReceiver:

```
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

if(intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)) {
    NetworkInfo networkInfo =
        intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
    if(networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        // Wifi is connected
        Log.d("Inetify", "Wifi is connected: " + String.valueOf(networkInfo));
    }
} else if(intent.getAction().equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {
    NetworkInfo networkInfo =
        intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
    if(networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI &&
        ! networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        // Wifi is disconnected
        Log.d("Inetify", "Wifi is disconnected: " + String.valueOf(networkInfo));
    }
}
}
```

Together with the following receiver element in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="ConnectivityActionReceiver"
    android:enabled="true" android:label="ConnectivityActionReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Some explanation:

- When only considering `ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION`, I always get two intents containing identical NetworkInfo instances (both getType() == TYPE_WIFI and isConnected() == true) when Wifi connects - the issue described in this question.
- When only using `WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION`, there is no intent broadcasted when Wifi disconnects, but two intents containing different NetworkInfo instances, allowing to determine one event when Wifi is connected.

NOTE: I've received one single crash report (NPE) where the `intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO)` returned null. So, even if it seems to be extremely rare to happen, it might be a good idea to add a null check.

Cheers,
Torsten

Comment: I'd like to mention here that, at least sometimes, the `WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` intent is broadcasted a short moment before the data connection is completely set up (DHCP configuration not complete) and that at that moment, `ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo()` might still return a `NetworkInfo` with type `TYPE_WIFI`.

Comment: I can personally confirm everything written by Torsten. Thank you for your solution. I find it frustrating that there is not a cleaner and simpler solution. The most surprising thing is that this behaviour doesn't take place when wifi is disconnected. I'm not saying it is necessarily a bug, but it could be better documented.

Comment: Getting the NetworkInfo from the intent is now depreciated.
However its not clear why "they" don't expect this to remain stable.

Is anyone finding instability in getting the Networkinfo from the intent?

Comment: @BrillPappin Getting it from ConnectivityManager is deprecated, but this answer's discussion is focused on getting it from WifiManager which is still fine.  However, like the others I still get strange sequences of notifications.

Comment: Thanks, I asked the accounts to be merged!

Comment: intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO) is deprecated.

Comment: android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE is also deprecated in N, just letting future people be aware..

Answer (score 12):

If you're listening on `WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` you'll receive this twice because there are 2 methods in the `NetworkInfo`

- `isConnectedOrConnecting()`
- `isConnected()`

First time `isConnectedOrConnecting()` returns `true` and `isConnected()` `false`
Second time `isConnectedOrConnecting()` and `isConnected()` return `true`

Cheers

Comment: both methods return true for both events for me :)

Comment: This answer is not correct, `isConnected()` can return `true` both times.

Answer (score 7):

This is the proper way to register for connectivity changes on API 21 and higher. The following code can be placed in a base activity and that way you can expect every screen in your app (that inherits from this activity) to get these callbacks.

First, create a network callback which will monitor connectivity changes.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private val networkCallback: ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {

    // Implement the callback methods that are relevant to the actions you want to take.
    // I have implemented onAvailable for connecting and onLost for disconnecting.

    override fun onAvailable(network: Network?) {
        super.onAvailable(network)
    }

    override fun onLost(network: Network?) {
        super.onLost(network)
    }
}
```

Then, register and unregister this callback in the relevant spots.

```
override fun onResume() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        val cm = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as? ConnectivityManager
        cm?.registerNetworkCallback(NetworkRequest.Builder().build(), networkCallback)
    }
}
```

And unregister when appropriate.

```
override fun onPause() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        val cm = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as? ConnectivityManager
        cm?.unregisterNetworkCallback(networkCallback)
    }
}
```

Notice that there is a check for `Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP`. This functionality is only available in Lollipop and above. Be sure to have a plan for how to handle network status changes in Pre-Lollipop devices if you support less than API 21 in your app.

Answer (score 4):

Updated the code of Torsten, such that when WIFI gets disconnected, only the single appropriate broadcast is acted upon.

Used NetworkInfo.getDetailedState() == DetailedState.DISCONNECTED for the checking.

```
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)) {
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = intent
            .getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
        if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            // Wifi is connected
            Log.d("Inetify","Wifi is connected: " + String.valueOf(networkInfo));
        }
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(
        ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = intent
            .getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
        if (networkInfo.getDetailedState() == DetailedState.DISCONNECTED) {
            // Wifi is disconnected
            Log.d("Inetify","Wifi is disconnected: "+String.valueOf(networkInfo));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For whoever wonders the change is `if(networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI && ! networkInfo.isConnected())` ___to___ `if (networkInfo.getDetailedState() == DetailedState.DISCONNECTED)`

Comment: What about Wifi and Cellular data? I believe both will cause the BroadcastReceiver to trigger causing more calls.

Answer (score 3):

If you registered the activity as an intent listener then you will recieve the same message twice. Specifically, you need to choose whether you want to listen on the Package level (XML) or the programatic level.

If you set up a class for a broadcast reciever and attach the listen to it AND you attach an intent filter to the activity, then the message will be replicated twice.

I hope this solves your issue.

Comment: This is correct, you either create a Broadcast listener in the class OR the manifest, but not both.

Comment: Finally I can comment on this one... your answer is certainly correct, but I had registered the BroadcastReceiver only in the manifest.

Answer (score 2):

I solved twice call by using SharedPref with Time.

```
private static final Long SYNCTIME = 800L;
private static final String LASTTIMESYNC = "DATE";
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private static final String TAG = "Connection";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     Log.d(TAG, "Network connectivity change");
     sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

     final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
     final NetworkInfo ni = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (ni != null && ni.isConnected()) {   

            if(System.currentTimeMillis()-sharedPreferences.getLong(LASTTIMESYNC, 0)>=SYNCTIME)
            {
                sharedPreferences.edit().putLong(LASTTIMESYNC, System.currentTimeMillis()).commit();
                // Your code Here.
            }
     }
     else if (intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, Boolean.FALSE)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "There's no network connectivity");

    }
}
```

Because there is small delay between 1.call and 2.call (About 200 milisec). 
So in IF with time second call will stop and just first will continue.

Comment: As bad as this one sounds as a solution, it worked for me. I have tried semaphores and also synchronized blocks and none have worked well for me.

Answer (score 2):

I solved if with 
in

```
onCreate()
       intentFilter.addAction("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
       intentFilter.addAction("android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED");
       intentFilter.addAction("android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE");
       ctx.registerReceiver(outgoingReceiver, intentFilter);
```

in

```
BroadcastReceiver
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
if(intent.getAction().equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {
                NetworkInfo networkInfo =
                        intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
                if(networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI &&
                        networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                    // Wifi is connected
                    Log.d("Inetify", "Wifi is connected: " + String.valueOf(networkInfo));

                    Log.e("intent action", intent.getAction());
                    if (isNetworkConnected(context)){
                        Log.e("WiFi", "is Connected. Saving...");
                        try {
                            saveFilesToServer("/" + ctx.getString(R.string.app_name).replaceAll(" ", "_") + "/Temp.txt");
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }}


 boolean isNetworkConnected(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (ni != null) {
            Log.e("NetworkInfo", "!=null");

            try{
                //For 3G check
                boolean is3g = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
                        .isConnectedOrConnecting();
                //For WiFi Check
                boolean isWifi = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
                        .isConnected();

                Log.e("isWifi", "isWifi="+isWifi);
                Log.e("is3g", "is3g="+is3g);
                if (!isWifi)
                {

                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }

            }catch (Exception er){
                return false;
            }

        } else{
            Log.e("NetworkInfo", "==null");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by using the intent extra for NetworkInfo.
In the example below, onReceive event is fired only once if wifi is connected or mobile.

```
if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {

        NetworkInfo networkInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

        boolean screenIsOn = false;
        // Prüfen ob Screen on ist
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            screenIsOn = pm.isInteractive();
        } else {
            screenIsOn = pm.isScreenOn();
        }

        if (Helper.isNetworkConnected(context)) {
            if (networkInfo.isConnected() && networkInfo.isAvailable()) {
                Log.v(logTAG + "onReceive", "connected");

                if (networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                    Log.v(logTAG + "onReceive", "mobile connected");

                } else if (networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                    Log.v(logTAG + "onReceive", "wifi connected");
                }
            }
        }
```

and my helper:

```
    public static boolean isNetworkConnected(Context ctx) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    return ni != null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to receive it once, you can simply control it through variables.

```
 if (ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                NetworkInfo activeNetwork = intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
                if (activeNetwork != null) { // connected to the internet
                    if (activeNetwork.isConnected() && !isUpdated) {
                        if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                            // connected to wifi
                        } else if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                            // connected to the mobile provider's data plan
                        }

                        isUpdated = true;
                    } else {
                        isUpdated = false;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

When turning WIFI ON,

1. With MOBILE data ON, two broadcasts are sent:
    Broadcast #1 : MOBILE data disconnected, and
    Broadcast #2 : WIFI connected
2. With MOBILE data OFF, only one broadcast is sent:
    Broadcast #1 : WIFI connected

Similar behavior can be observed while turning the WIFI OFF under the above two conditions.

To distinguish between the two, please follow #2 and #3 below:

```
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d(TAG, "*** Action: " + intent.getParcelableExtra("networkInfo"));

            NetworkInfo netInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra("networkInfo");

            if(intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE")) {
                ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                        = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo activeNetInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                if (activeNetInfo != null) {
                    if (netInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                        if (netInfo.getState().name().contains("DISCONNECTED")
                                && activeNetInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "WIFI disconnect created this broadcast. MOBILE data ON."); // #1
                        } else if (netInfo.getState().name().contains("CONNECTED")
                                && activeNetInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "WIFI connect created this broadcast."); // #2
                        }
                    } else if (netInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                        if (netInfo.getState().name().contains("DISCONNECTED")
                                && activeNetInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "MOBILE data disconnect created this broadcast. WIFI ON."); // #3
                        } else if (netInfo.getState().name().contains("CONNECTED")
                                && activeNetInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "MOBILE data connect created this broadcast."); // #4
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "No network available");
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I handled it, was simply by saving the state of the network and then comparing it to see if there was a *change*.

```
public class ConnectivityChangedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        boolean previouslyConnected = MyApp.getInstance().isNetworkPreviouslyConnected();
        boolean currentlyConnected = MyApp.getInstance().isNetworkConnected();

        if (previouslyConnected != currentlyConnected) {
            // do something and reset
            MyApp.getInstance().resetNetworkPreviouslyConnected();
        }
    }

}
```

If this is the approach you take, it's important to reset it in `onResume` of your fragment or activity, so that it holds the current value:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    MyApp.getInstance().resetNetworkPreviouslyConnected();
}
```

I did that in my `BaseFragment`, a parent of all fragments in my app.

Answer (score 0):

check networkType from intent
and compare activeNetworkInfo.getType()

```
                 Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                 ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                 NetworkInfo ni = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

                 if(ni != null && ni.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                     if(bundle.getInt("networkType") == ni.getType()) {
                         // active network intent
                     }
                 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a special case for network connectivity saying there is no internet but actually there is. It turns out `getActiveNetworkInfo` will always return you **DISCONNECTED/BLOCKED** in a specific case when network is changed while battery level is low and app was just switched

Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34884442/android-checking-network-connectivity-return-not-connected-when-connected-to-wi/45231746#45231746)

Answer (score -2):

Only listen to action "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE". It's broadcasted whenever connection is established or destroyed.

"android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" will be broadcasted when connection established. So you get two triggers.

Enjoy!

Comment: The problem is that it sends two events for each sate change.