# How to trigger BroadcastReceiver when I turn on/off Mobile Cellular Data(Mobile Internet)

Tags: android

I want to know how to trigger **BroadcastReceiver** if I **turn on/off mobile cellular data**. I already registered BroadcastReceiver and **it is working fine if I turn on/off wifi but if I turn on/off cellular data no broadcast trigger. can anyone please help me about this?**

**Here is my code.**

Here I register **BroadcastReceiver** in **Manifest.file**

```
       <receiver android:name="com.servicesandroid.NetworkCheckReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

**Manifest permissions**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Here is my **BroadcastReceiver class.**

```
public class NetworkCheckReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(context, "Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         Log.d("app","Network connectivity change");
    }

}
```

Comment: do you have working cellular data connection?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to specify appropriate permissions and do the needful as mentioned below:

**Permissions in manifest:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

**Receiver declaration in manifest:**

```
        <receiver
        android:name=".NetworkCheckReceiver"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**NetworkCheckReceiver class file:**

```
public class NetworkCheckReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {
            Log.d("NetworkCheckReceiver", "NetworkCheckReceiver invoked...");


            boolean noConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(
                    ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);

            if (!noConnectivity) {
                Log.d("NetworkCheckReceiver", "connected");
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("NetworkCheckReceiver", "disconnected");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**Note:**

Make sure you have working mobile cellular data connection. This receiver won't trigger if you don't have internet pack and you just switching on/off. You surely **need to have working connection** to test.

Comment: Yes, its working now. My cellular data plan was not active thats why it wasn't working. thanks @Mehul

Comment: Following two permissions are sufficient`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>` if you will give `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>` too `BroadcastReceiver` `onReceive` method call two times when you turn on/off wifi connection.

Comment: @ChintanBawa: I'm glad to help. you can either skip that permission or you can do something as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5890104/1288725) to checkout further about connection type. i.e. mobile,wifi

Comment: @MehulJoisar Can you share code of..How to get result form broadcast receiver to my acitivity.....

Comment: @GowthamanM You may use LocalBroadcastManager to broadcast from onReceive of NetworkCheckReceiver and to receive on your Activity.

Comment: @MehulJoisar I solved my pbm sir.....Thank you so much for your responce

Answer (score 2):

Try the following this will receives when  the mobile data and wifi changes

```
 public class NetworkCheckReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see android.content.BroadcastReceiver#onReceive(android.content.Context,
         * android.content.Intent)
         */
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.e("NetworkCheckReceiver","ConnectionChangeReceiver.onReceive()");
            String statusString = getConnectivityStatusString(context);
            Toast.makeText(context, statusString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        public int TYPE_WIFI = 1;
        public int TYPE_MOBILE = 2;
        public int TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED = 0;

        public int getConnectivityStatus(Context context) {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (null != activeNetwork) {
                if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
                    return TYPE_WIFI;

                if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
                    return TYPE_MOBILE;
            }
            return TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED;
        }

        public String getConnectivityStatusString(Context context) {
            int conn = getConnectivityStatus(context);
            String status = null;
            if (conn == TYPE_WIFI) {
                status = "Wifi enabled";
            } else if (conn == TYPE_MOBILE) {
                status = "Mobile data enabled";
            } else if (conn == TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED) {
                status = "Not connected to Internet";
            }
            return status;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I already given permissions. Sorry, I forgot to mention them.

Comment: I tried this code before and try it now also but its just broadcast for wifi not for mobile cellular data. Did u tried this code.

Comment: yes it is working for both mobile data as well as wifi and i updated the code by adding log messages once the mobile data and wifi enabled or disabled it will receives check the log messages  @Chintan

Comment: My cellular data plan was not active thats why it wasn't working. thanx @hareesh