# Automatically connect to wifi network in android?

Tags: android

I am develping an app in which whenever wifi turned on then in background app should be to connect to a network if the network it connected to previously ?Can i use broad cast reciver for this purpose?

Comment: I think you need to used `BroadcastReceiver` as well as other components such as `WifiManager` and `NetworkManager`

Comment: can i detect if wifi network availble using brodcast reciver & then connect to the network which previosly remember.

Comment: Why not. I guess you have to first read the saved Wi-Fi networks and then listen to the broadcasts.

Comment: This will get you on the right track. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27559837/how-to-trigger-broadcastreceiver-when-i-turn-on-off-mobile-cellular-datamobile

Comment: I want to listen to broadcast first & then i get the previous saved wifi ssid & password from database then i try to match with searched result.if reslut match with previous then i connect to that network

Comment: hi , please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290/how-to-connect-to-a-specific-wifi-network-in-android-programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For receiving the `Broadcast` for connectivity change, you can listen like this:

Register your receiver in the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
    <receiver
            android:name=".NetworkCheckReceiver"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
```

Then in the `BroadcastReceiver` class

```
public class NetworkCheckReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {
                Log.d("NetworkCheckReceiver", "NetworkCheckReceiver invoked...");


                boolean noConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(
                        ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);

                if (!noConnectivity) {
                    Log.d("NetworkCheckReceiver", "connected");
                    WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
                    wifiConfig.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", networkSSID);
                    wifiConfig.preSharedKey = String.format("\"%s\"", networkKey);
                    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

                    int netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig);
                    wifiManager.disconnect();
                    wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
                    wifiManager.reconnect();
                }
                else{
                    Log.d("NetworkCheckReceiver", "disconnected");
                }
            }
        }
 }
```

And of course, don't forget to add the required permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Comment: what is networkSSID and networkKey here. If we dont have any then what to do in that case?

Comment: @theLazyFinder the purpose of above code is auto connect to a wifi connection therefore SSID and key will have to be defined. SSID is the WiFi connection name and key is its password to connect