# Got NetworkInfo state:DISCONNECTED/BLOCKED even if phone is connected

Tags: android

I have understood internet connection by used below code. When app is foreground, `NetworkInfo` connection state is `CONNECTED` but app is background or killed, connection state is `DISCONNECTED/BLOCKED` even if phone is connected 3G.

I looked [another questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34884442/android-checking-network-connectivity-return-not-connected-when-connected-to-wi?rq=1) by stackoverflow but there is no answer to this problem.

```
public class InternetConnectionControl {

    private NetworkInfo networkInfo;

    private NetworkInfo getNetworkInfo() {

        if (networkInfo == null) {
            ConnectivityManager _cm = ServiceUtil.getConnectivityManager(MyApplication.getContext());
            networkInfo = _cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        }

        return networkInfo;
    }

    public void setNetworkInfo(NetworkInfo networkInfo) {
        this.networkInfo = networkInfo;
    }

    private boolean isConnectedToWifi() {
        NetworkInfo info = getNetworkInfo();
        return (info != null && info.isConnectedOrConnecting() && info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    }

    private boolean isConnectedToMobile() {
        NetworkInfo info = getNetworkInfo();
        return (info != null && info.isConnectedOrConnecting() && info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    }

    public boolean isConnectedToInternet() {

        boolean isWifiConnected = isConnectedToWifi();
        boolean isMobileConnected = isConnectedToMobile();

        return isWifiConnected || isMobileConnected;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You device is Samsung? Samsung has a power save mode and you have to allow below ways your app:

**Step 1**

1. Enter Battery from Settings
2. Clicked Unmonitored apps
3. Add your app

---

**Step2**

1. Enter Apps from Settings
2. Tap your app
3. Tap Mobile data
4. Enable Allow app while Data saver on