# Detect when connected/disconntected to Wi-Fi

Tags: java, android, android-wifi

I want to know when phone lost connection with Wi-Fi. I know that I should use Broadcast Receiver. So I registered the Broadcast Receiver:

```
intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
registerReceiver(wifiScanReceiver, intentFilter);
```

Then I created Broadcast Receiver:

```
public class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public WifiScanReceiver() {

    }

    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("TAG", "trigged");
    }
}
```

Then I connect to Wi-Fi and when I turn on/off router - nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

I have all permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Make sure you have modified Manifest file for Internet Permission as well..If Not yet.Also [this post](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-check-wifi-internet-connection/) might help

Comment: @eRaisedToX yep, i did it..

Comment: Are you able to detect Internet ,I mean other than wifi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

As far as I can see you have not declared the `BroadcastReceiver`, adding permission alone would not trigger your broadcast receiver.

My solution is based on declaring it via manifest, but that said your problem is I can not see you have declared broadcaster class in your code, so you can chose declare it in manifest or in your code.

So try to declare it and it should works. I have tested your code with both declaration and it works:

```
<receiver android:name=".WifiScanReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Or declare it programmatically `new WifiScanReceiver()` in onCreate method:

```
final IntentFilter filters = new IntentFilter();
filters.addAction("android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE");
super.registerReceiver(new WifiScanReceiver(), filters);
```

You will need this also ([reference](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html)) in your WifiScanReceiver:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        ConnectivityManager cm =
                (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isWiFi = activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI;

        if (isWiFi) {
            Log.i("TAG", "trigged");
        }
    }
```

Comment: it returns 4 times, but I need only once

Comment: here is the solution, the reason it was called 4 times, no it is called twice, and you find the explaining here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276032/connectivity-action-intent-received-twice-when-wifi-connected

Answer (score 1):

Try with the ConnectivityManager class put this inside onReceive

```
ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE); 
    NetworkInfo netInfo = conMan.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) 
        // Connection Successful 
    else
        // Connection  Failed 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have granted **permissions** in Manifest for Internet and Network access, that part is okay.

Further,

You may try **ConnectivityManager** Class for checking net /wifi connectivity to your device .

```
public boolean checkMobileInternetConn() {
        //Create object for ConnectivityManager class which returns network related info
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        //If connectivity object is not null
        if (connectivity != null) {
            //Get network info - WIFI internet access
            NetworkInfo info = connectivity.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

            if (info != null) {
                //Look for whether device is currently connected to WIFI network
                if (info.isConnected()) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

(Refer [this post](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-check-wifi-internet-connection/) for complete code.)

Try this n feel free to revert back :)

Comment: When I turn off router it returns 4 times "false". When device connecting back again there is no one true..

Comment: I need return false when connection with WI-FI lost and return true when connection is restored