# How to enable/disable downloading on mobile data

Tags: java, android, android-studio, download, settings

Just like in Google Play Store you have an option to only update the apps over Wifi and not over Mobile Data connection i.e " Auto-update apps over Wi-Fi only." or an option to Update apps through both Mobile and Wifi

I am developing an applications that will download some media files from a server but i want to enable an option that the user can toggle if they want to only download over wifi or download through both
Any help/suggestion will be welcome

Comment: [refer this link i hope it will help you!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32236842/2794507)

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [this guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing) on network usage management.

You can use `NetworkInfo` to achieve what you're looking for:

> NetworkInfo: Describes the status of a network interface of a given
>   type (currently either Mobile or Wi-Fi).

```
private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "NetworkStatusExample";
...
ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
        getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
boolean isWifiConn = networkInfo.isConnected();
networkInfo = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
boolean isMobileConn = networkInfo.isConnected();
Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Wifi connected: " + isWifiConn);
Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Mobile connected: " + isMobileConn);
```

If the user chose to download only over Wi-Fi, you can reject the operation when the network used is not Wi-Fi.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) and define the network type from [JobInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkRequest.Builder#addTransportType(int))

Simple guide [here](https://catinean.com/2014/10/19/smart-background-tasks-with-jobscheduler/)

```
    JobInfo job = new JobInfo.Builder(JOB_ID, new ComponentName(this, UpdateJobService.class))  
   .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
   .setRequiresCharging(true)
   .build();
```