# Two instances of the same network when searching wifi network

Tags: android, kotlin, wifi, android-wifi

I am trying to connect to a device via wifi

```
final WifiNetworkSpecifier wifiNetworkSpecifier = new WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder()
                .setSsidPattern(new PatternMatcher(networkSSIDPattern, PatternMatcher.PATTERN_PREFIX))
                .setWpa2Passphrase(passWord)
                .build();


final NetworkRequest networkRequest = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
                .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
                .removeCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
                .setNetworkSpecifier(wifiNetworkSpecifier)
                .build();


connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) RainBird.getContext().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

connectivityManager.requestNetwork(networkRequest, networkCallback);
```

I am getting a dialog with the good device network, after connecting, the same network appears two times in the dialog.

how can I fix it?

First connection view:
[image]

after one connection, the same network appears 2 times:
[image]

The problem only occurs on android12

Comment: Seems like your networkSSIDPattern is matching two networks? Is it possible you are showing both bands of a dual-band Wi-Fi network?

Comment: It is only happening on android12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android 12 WifiNetworkSpecifier API is only for peer-to-peer local-only network which means it must NOT have NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET.
For more information please check [this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-bootstrap#code-sample).
If you are looking for an internet connection, please use [WifiNetworkSuggestion API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-suggest).

Answer (score 1):

I believe that [Mike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54538895/15749574) might help you:

> This is the proper way to register for connectivity changes on API 21 and higher. The following code can be placed in a base activity and that way you can expect every screen in your app (that inherits from this activity) to get these callbacks.

> First, create a network callback which will monitor connectivity changes.

```kotlin
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private val networkCallback: ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {

    override fun onAvailable(network: Network?) {
        super.onAvailable(network)
    }

    override fun onLost(network: Network?) {
        super.onLost(network)
    }
}
```

> Then, register and unregister this callback in the relevant spots.

```
override fun onResume() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        val cm = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as? ConnectivityManager
        cm?.registerNetworkCallback(NetworkRequest.Builder().build(), networkCallback)
    }
}
```

```
override fun onPause() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        val cm = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as? ConnectivityManager
        cm?.unregisterNetworkCallback(networkCallback)
    }
}
```

Comment: this didn't fix the problem, I still see 2 networks

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the solution
I just changed compileSdkVersion from 30 to 31

ConnectivityManager in android 12 (version 31) contain the fix

thank you every one

Actually this did fix the problem for my pixel 6
I still can reproduce the problem on samsung S22...